# Class that implements an interface in a jar, but does not override the methods

Tags: java, apache-commons-dbcp

My project has a dependency to apache commons-dbcp and we are using version 1.2.2

The commons-dbcp version we are using has the class `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` which implements `javax.sql.DataSource` which in turn implements `java.sql.Wrapper`, however `BasicDataSource` does not implement the methods defined in `Wrapper` (jdk 1.6.x). But my project which has a class (`MyClass`) that extends `BasicDataSource` compiles without any problems - I am a bit puzzled here. In IntelliJ, I see `MyClass` as an error though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That class has been compiled with an earlier version of the `javax.sql.DataSource` interface (the Java 5 or earlier version). The `Wrapper` interface was introduced with Java 6 / JDBC 4.0.

When the classloader loads a class that implements an interface, but doesn't implement all the new methods, it allows it. When the method is actually called, a `NoSuchMethodError` is thrown (I believe it stubs the missing methods to throw this exception). This allows for - limited - forward compatibility: as long as that method isn't actually called the implementation will work.

This also means that when you subclass this class it will behave as if all methods have been implemented (even if they weren't), as long as the source of that class isn't part of your project.